# element.classList.add not working did I do something wrong?

Tags: javascript

code:

```
try {
            let before_column = allColumns[allColumns.indexOf(current_column) - 1].children;
            if (before_column[current_postition - 2] != undefined && before_column[current_postition - 2].children.length != 0) {
                if (before_column[current_postition - 2].children[0].className.split(" ")[1] == "blackpiece") {
                    before_column[current_postition - 2].classList.add("attackedwhite");
                    knightAttacked.push(before_column[current_postition - 2]);
                }
                if (before_column[current_postition - 2].children[0].className.split(" ")[1] == "whitepiece") {
                    before_column[current_postition - 2].classList.add("protectedwhite");
                    knightProtected.push(before_column[current_postition - 2]);
                }
            }
            else {
                before_column[current_postition - 2].classList.add("protectedwhite");
                knightProtected.push(before_column[current_postition - 2]);
            }
        }

        catch (er){
            console.log(er);
        }
```

Error:

**TypeError: before_column[(current_postition - 2)].classList.add is not a function**

I know about the toggle function but I need the add to work my project requires the add function and can't be done with the toggle function. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What value does `current_postition` have when this error occurs?  If you subtract two from that value, is it less than zero?  Arrays don't have negative indexed elements.

Comment: current_position holds a value of 7 when the error throws

Comment: And what is the value of `before_column[current_postition - 2]`when the error occurs?

Comment: it holds a value of 5 and the console.log(before_column[current_position - 2]) returns a div so it is defined but idk why it is erroring